# Creating a textbox with a new syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

In my Asp.NET page I have one html editor. 
When user write below part, and click the save button this text is saved in database and gets the id number like (Id=12) and I get it from user interface side of web site with a page with below code.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 ...
 ..
 .
</body>
</html>
```

I can get the saved text like below sql statement

```
SELECT Text FROM StackOverFlow WHERE Id = 12
```

And then I can show the value in web page.

In this respect I want to use this editor to create a asp.net textbox.

That is to say I want to create a new syntax which supply to editor entering basic sentences to create asp.net textbox.

Let's assume that syntax is below:

{{inputbox}}

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<li>
     {{inputbox}}
</li>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I create an asp.net textbox with using a new syntax like {{inputbox}}?
Can you give any advice to illuminate me?

Comment: It is unclear where you want the textbox to be generated.  Server? Client (markdown-style)?

Comment: at the server site I want to generate textbox with defined syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use some replace operations in HTML.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<li>
     {{inputbox}}
</li>
</body>
</html>
```

I found {{ ...... }} and replace and dynamically create what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try looking at how the Razor view engine works.  Or any ASP.net view engine.

Answer (score -2):

You can try to do it using JQuery on client side by replacing {{inputbox}} with Text box.

```
    var htmlStr = $(this).html();
    htmlStr.replace('{{inputbox}}', '<asp:TextBox ID="DynamicName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>');
    $(this).html(htmlStr);
```

Comment: jQuery is a client-side technology.. you can not use it to embed aspnet server controls.

Comment: I have been searching solution about server side.